# Is compiling opencv with tbb relevant on processeur with 2 thread

Tags: opencv, tbb, hyperthreading

I am using OpenCv with the following processor :
Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N455   @ 1.66GHz
Intel indicates that this processeur has 1 core but 2 threads.
So would it be relevent to use OpenCv with TBB option and expect faster execution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help.

TBB example works better using 2 threads even on my Megafon Mint phone that contains Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU Z2460 @ 1.6GHz processor which has 1 core but 2 threads also.

--Vladimir